# Creating a bibliography with fixed indention and authoryear labels using biblatex and biber

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, indentation, labels

I am using biblatex and biber with the authoryear styles for my documents. Now I've been asked to format my bibliography like this:
[image]

It looks like a mixture of the numeric style (labels left of the entry) and authoryear. However, the length of the label is much longer and might for the first line of the entry to wrap. How can I archieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *edit*: `biblatex-ext` has this function built in as `introcite=label`. And so the code below can be replaced with
>
> ```
> \documentclass{article}
> \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
> \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
> \usepackage[british]{babel}
> \usepackage{csquotes}
> \usepackage[style=ext-authoryear, backend=biber, introcite=label, dashed=false]{biblatex}
> \addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
>
> \setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.5\baselineskip plus 0.5\baselineskip}
> \setlength{\introcitewidth}{6em}
>
> \begin{document}
> \cite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,knuth:ct:a}
> \printbibliography
> \end{document}
> ```
>
> The styles of `biblatex-ext` can be used as drop-in replacements of the corresponding standard styles.

Try this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber,dashed=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.5\baselineskip plus 0.5\baselineskip}

\newsavebox\ay@labelbox
\newlength{\labwidthsameline}
\setlength{\labwidthsameline}{6em}

\newbibmacro{labelwidthbib}{%
  \begingroup
  \delimcontext{cite}%
  \DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperref}{##1}%
  \csuse{blx@hook@cite}%
  \csuse{blx@hook@citekey}%
  \citetrackerfalse\pagetrackerfalse\backtrackerfalse
  \defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxcitenames}%
  \usebibmacro{cite}%
  \endgroup
} 
%-----------------------
\newbibmacro{kicklabel}{% 
  \sbox\ay@labelbox{\usebibmacro{labelwidthbib}}%
  \global\togglefalse{blx@insert}%
  \ifdim\wd\ay@labelbox>\labwidthsameline
    \leavevmode\newline
  \fi
}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}%
  {\list
    {\usebibmacro{labelwidthbib}}%
    {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labwidthsameline}%
     \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
     \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
     \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
     \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
     \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
     \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}}%
  {\endlist}%
  {\item\usebibmacro{kicklabel}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,knuth:ct:a}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

This is inspired largely by https://github.com/LukasCBossert/biblatex-archaeologie/issues/79 and https://github.com/LukasCBossert/biblatex-archaeologie/issues/58

Comment: This is great and the code I am using. How would we modify it so that the YEAR label goes to the second line (of the left-hand tag area)?

Comment: @GyaltenJigdrel Please ask a new question about that.