# Biblatex custom style: Year in parantheses in bibliography but not in text

Tags: biblatex

I used the following custom style to create a bibliography matching the requirements of our institution:
[Creating a bibliography with fixed indention and authoryear labels using biblatex and biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348126/creating-a-bibliography-with-fixed-indention-and-authoryear-labels-using-biblate)

It successfully creates a bibliography with labels and intended entries. However, the label looks like this:

> author year

This is true for both the in-text citation and the label in bibliography. What I need is

> author year     [at position of `\parencite`]
>
> author (year)     [in bibliography]
>            rest of bibliography entry

Comment: If you have applied any changes to the code in the other answer an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) of what you have now would be appreciated (and is probably necessary to make sure everything works as expected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With `biblatex-ext` as suggested in the update to [Creating a bibliography with fixed indention and authoryear labels using biblatex and biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/348126/35864) this is much easier now. You can simply redefine the inner cite delims of `bbx@introcite`.
>
> ```
> \documentclass{article}
> \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
> \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
> \usepackage[british]{babel}
> \usepackage{csquotes}
> \usepackage[style=ext-authoryear, backend=biber, introcite=label, dashed=false]{biblatex}
> \addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
>
> \setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.5\baselineskip plus 0.5\baselineskip}
> \setlength{\introcitewidth}{6em}
>
> \DeclareInnerCiteDelims{bbx@introcite}{\bibopenparen}{\bibcloseparen}
>
> \begin{document}
> \cite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,knuth:ct:a}
> \printbibliography
> \end{document}
> ```

You only need `\usebibmacro{textcite}` instead of `\usebibmacro{cite}` as well as a few tiny modifications for `textcite`.

The only part that is changed from the other answer to [Creating a bibliography with fixed indention and authoryear labels using biblatex and biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/348126/35864) is

```
\newbibmacro{labelwidthbib}{%
  \begingroup
  \DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperref}{##1}%
  \csuse{blx@hook@cite}%
  \csuse{blx@hook@citekey}%
  \citetrackerfalse\pagetrackerfalse\backtrackerfalse
  \global\undef\cbx@lasthash
  \global\undef\cbx@lastyear
  \defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxcitenames}%
  \boolfalse{cbx:parens}%
  \usebibmacro{textcite}%
  \ifbool{cbx:parens}
     {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
     {}%
  \endgroup
}
```

In total

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber,dashed=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.5\baselineskip plus 0.5\baselineskip}

\newsavebox\ay@labelbox
\newlength{\labwidthsameline}
\setlength{\labwidthsameline}{6em}

\newbibmacro{labelwidthbib}{%
  \begingroup
  \DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperref}{##1}%
  \csuse{blx@hook@cite}%
  \csuse{blx@hook@citekey}%
  \citetrackerfalse\pagetrackerfalse\backtrackerfalse
  \global\undef\cbx@lasthash
  \global\undef\cbx@lastyear
  \defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxcitenames}%
  \boolfalse{cbx:parens}%
  \usebibmacro{textcite}%
  \ifbool{cbx:parens}
     {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
     {}%
  \endgroup
} 
%-----------------------
\newbibmacro{kicklabel}{% 
  \sbox\ay@labelbox{\usebibmacro{labelwidthbib}}%
  \global\togglefalse{blx@insert}%
  \ifdim\wd\ay@labelbox>\labwidthsameline
    \leavevmode\newline
  \fi
}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}%
  {\list
    {\usebibmacro{labelwidthbib}}%
    {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labwidthsameline}%
     \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
     \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
     \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
     \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
     \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
     \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}}%
  {\endlist}%
  {\item\usebibmacro{kicklabel}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Comment: Note that this solution still leaves `\parencite` to show bracketed citations, if you want no brackets use `\cite` as in the MWE.

Comment: \parencite is fine for me. I just need to change the bibliography itself. Its an requirement to get my thesis printed. Thank you so much, it looks good now!