# Custom BibLaTeX bib with two blocks and authors below each other?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, custom-bib

I want to create a custom bibliography with BibLaTeX. I got to a point where it almost looks as required, but I'm not able to split the bibliography into two columns and I also don't know how to write the authors below each other.

Desired output: [image: Desired Output]

Current output: [image: Current Output]

My code:
    %!TEX root = ../root.tex

```
% Formats the bibliography environment
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{0.2\textwidth}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}


\makeatletter
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \global\undef\bbx@lasthash%
  \clearfield{extrayear}}
\makeatother

% Adds ":" after authors.
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}

% Commas between units
\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

% Delimiter between multiple authors:
\renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}

% Delimiter between last two authors:
\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}

% More space between entries
\setlength\bibitemsep{2\itemsep}

% Lastname, Firstname for all authors
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

% Remove url prefix
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}

% o.J. if no date is given
\newcommand{\mkbibnodate}{\addcomma \space o\adddot J\adddot}
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \iffieldundef{year}
   {\mkbibnodate}
  {\usebibmacro{date}}
  \newunit}

% Makes title in this Format: (Shorttitle) Title
\renewbibmacro*{title}{%
  \printfield[parens]{shorttitle}%
  \setunit{\space}%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newunit}

% Bibliography style online, modified
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{online}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  %\usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  %\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{subtitle}
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iffieldundef{year}
   {\mkbibnodate}
  {\usebibmacro{date}}
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{url+urldate}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

% Bibliography style book, modified
  \DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{subtitle}
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

Thank you for any help in advance!

Edit:

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authortitle,citestyle=authortitle,hyperref=true,autocite=footnote,sortlocale=de_DE,dashed=false,maxnames=99]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{chickenlittle,
    author      = {Jesus Bisbal and Deirdre Lawless and Bing Wu and Jane Grimson and Vincent Wade and Ray Richardson and Donie O'Sullivan},
    title       = {A Survey of Research into Legacy System Migration},
    shorttitle  = {Legacy Migration},
    institution = {Trinity College},
    publisher   = {Trinity College},
    year        = {1997},
    url         = {http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.50.9051},
    urldate     = {2018-07-11}
}

@online{incmigration,
    author      = {Michael L. Brodie and Michael Stonebraker},
    title       = {DARWIN: On the Incremental Migration of Legacy Information Systems 1},
    shorttitle  = {Incremental Migration},
    year        = {1993},
    institution = {University of California},
    publisher   = {University of California},
    month       = {3},
    urldate     = {2018-07-11},
    url         = {http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.70.2950}
}

@online{porting,
    author      = "{Microsoft Corporation}",
    title       = {Porting to .NET Core from .NET Framework},
    shorttitle  = {Porting in .NET},
    date        = {2016-06-20},
    url         = {https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/},
    urldate     = {2018-06-26}
}
@online{netframeworkfirstrelease,
    author      = "{Microsoft Corporation}",
    title       = {.NET Framework Versions and Dependencies},
    shorttitle  = {.NET Framework Initial Release},
    date        = {2018-05-31},
    urldate     = {2018-07-09},
    url         = {https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies}
}

@online{whatisdotnet,
    author      = "{Microsoft Corporation}",
    title       = {What is .NET?},
    shorttitle  = {What is .NET?},
    date        = {2018-07-06},
    urldate     = {2018-07-06},
    url         = {https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/what-is-dotnet}
}

@online{azureiotedge,
    author      = "{Microsoft Corporation}",
    title       = {What is Azure IoT Edge},
    shorttitle  = {Azure IoT Edge},
    date        = {2018-06-12},
    urldate     = {2018-07-02},
    url         = {https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/iot-edge/about-iot-edge}
}

@online{netapianal,
    author      = "{Microsoft Corporation}",
    title       = {.NET API analyzer},
    shorttitle  = {.NET API analyzer},
    date        = {2018-07-02},
    urldate     = {2018-05-31},
    url         = {https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/standard/analyzers/api-analyzer}
}
\end{filecontents}



\makeatletter
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \global\undef\bbx@lasthash%
  \clearfield{extrayear}}
\makeatother

% Adds ":" after authors.
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}

% Commas between units
\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

% Delimiter between multiple authors:
\renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}

% Delimiter between last two authors:
\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}

% More space between entries
\setlength\bibitemsep{2\itemsep}

% Lastname, Firstname for all authors
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

% Remove url prefix
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}

% o.J. if no date is given
\newcommand{\mkbibnodate}{\addcomma \space o\adddot J\adddot}
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \iffieldundef{year}
   {\mkbibnodate}
  {\usebibmacro{date}}
  \newunit}

% Makes title in this Format: (Shorttitle) Title
\renewbibmacro*{title}{%
  \printfield[parens]{shorttitle}%
  \setunit{\space}%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newunit}

% Bibliography style online, modified
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{online}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \printtext{\newline}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{subtitle}
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iffieldundef{year}
   {\mkbibnodate}
  {\usebibmacro{date}}
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{url+urldate}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

% Bibliography style book, modified
  \DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \printtext{\newline}%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{subtitle}
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{document}

\cite{porting}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Biber/BibLaTeX Versions: latest

Comment: You will need a tabular bibliography: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71088/35864 That requires some intricate changes to internals.

Comment: Do you have to follow this two-column style? I think it looks quite bad with several authors or longer names. So if you are allowed some artistic license I would definitely advise you to not go down that route. You could try `biblatex-philosophy`'s `philosophy-modern` for a fancy style that similarly emphasises the authors, but does not suffer from the disadvantages of tables.

Comment: @moewe Thank you! I'll look into it. Yes, I'm forced to implement their ugly MS Word requirements...

Comment: Can you please show us a complete minimal example (with `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}...\end{document}`, a few bib entries and so forth), so we can have a proper look at your question. See [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) and [How to write a MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). That will make it much easier for us to help you.

Comment: Oh while you are producing the [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) please tell us which version of `biblatex` (and Biber) you are using. The current versions are 3.11/2.11

Comment: @moewe I updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tabular bibliographies have been integrated into [`biblatex-ext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext). If you load the support package `biblatex-ext-tabular` the code below reduces to
>
> ```
> \documentclass[british]{article}
> \usepackage{babel}
> \usepackage{csquotes}
> \usepackage[backend=biber, style=authortitle, autocite=footnote, dashed=false, maxnames=99]{biblatex}
> \usepackage{hyperref}
>
>
> \DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}
> \renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
> \DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
> \DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}
>
> \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
>
> \DeclareFieldFormat*{shorttitle}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
> \DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}
>
> \renewbibmacro*{date}{%
>   \iffieldundef{year}
>     {\printtext{\bibstring{nodate}}}
>     {\printdate}}
>
> \makeatletter
>
> \usepackage{biblatex-ext-tabular}
>
> % sortname labels (a robust style should add provision for missing  labelnames)
> \newbibmacro*{sortname}{%
>   \ifnameundef{labelname}
>     {\printtext[bold]{No name given.}%
>      \PackageWarning{biblatex}{No labelname for entry \thefield{entrykey},\MessageBreak
>        we need to think of something else}}
>     {\printnames[sortname]{labelname}%
>      \iffieldequalstr{labelnamesource}{editor}
>        {\setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
>         \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}}
>        {\iffieldequalstr{labelnamesource}{translator}
>           {\setunit{\printdelim{translatortypedelim}}%
>            \usebibmacro{translator+othersstrg}}
>           {}}}}
>
> \usepackage{array}
> \newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
> \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
> \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
>
> \usepackage{longtable}
> % demo new tabular bibliography format
> % I strongly prefer left-aligned with fixed width (L)
> % over justified (p) here
> % longtable for tables that break over pages
> \defbibtabular{bibtabular}
>   {\def\arraystretch{2}%
>    \begin{longtable}{@{}L{\dimexpr0.3\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax}L{\dimexpr0.7\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax}@{}}}
>   {\end{longtable}}
>   {\anchorlang{\usebibmacro{sortname}} &
>    \driver{\usebibmacro{tabular:omitsortname}} \\}
>
> \renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
>   \printfield{shorttitle}%
>   \printunit*{\addspace}}
>
> \usepackage{filecontents}
> \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
> @online{chickenlittle,
>     author      = {Jesus Bisbal and Deirdre Lawless and Bing Wu and Jane Grimson and Vincent Wade and Ray Richardson and Donie O'Sullivan},
>     title       = {A Survey of Research into Legacy System Migration},
>     shorttitle  = {Legacy Migration},
>     institution = {Trinity College},
>     publisher   = {Trinity College},
>     year        = {1997},
>     url         = {http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.50.9051},
>     urldate     = {2018-07-11}
> }
>
> @online{incmigration,
>     author      = {Michael L. Brodie and Michael Stonebraker},
>     title       = {DARWIN: On the Incremental Migration of Legacy Information Systems 1},
>     shorttitle  = {Incremental Migration},
>     year        = {1993},
>     institution = {University of California},
>     publisher   = {University of California},
>     month       = {3},
>     urldate     = {2018-07-11},
>     url         = {http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.70.2950}
> }
>
> @online{porting,
>     author      = {{Microsoft Corporation}},
>     title       = {Porting to .NET Core from .NET Framework},
>     shorttitle  = {Porting in .NET},
>     date        = {2016-06-20},
>     url         = {https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/},
>     urldate     = {2018-06-26}
> }
> \end{filecontents}
> \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
> \addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
>
> \begin{document}
> \cite{porting,incmigration,chickenlittle,
>   sigfridsson,ctan,westfahl:frontier,
>   knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,worman,geer,nussbaum}
>
> \printbibtabular
> \end{document}
> ```

Here is a solution based on [Audrey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4483/audrey)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71454/35864) to [tabular bibliography with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71088/35864). Because of changes to internal macros, the code of Audrey's answer was changed very slightly. I have also modernised your code ans shortened it where possible.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authortitle, autocite=footnote, dashed=false, maxnames=99]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}
\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{shorttitle}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{date}{%
  \iffieldundef{year}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{nodate}}}
    {\printdate}}

\makeatletter

% user-level command for printing tabular bibliography
\let\printbibtabular\printbibliography
\patchcmd{\printbibtabular}{\blx@printbibliography}{\bbx@printbibtabular}{}{}
\patchcmd{\printbibtabular}{\blx@printbibliography}{\bbx@printbibtabular}{}{}
\let\bbx@printbibtabular\blx@printbibliography
\patchcmd{\bbx@printbibtabular}{\blx@bibliography}{\bbx@bibtabular}{}{}
\patchcmd{\bbx@printbibtabular}
  {\def\blx@theenv{bibliography}}{\def\blx@theenv{bibtabular}}{}{}


% underlying macros
\def\bbx@bibtabular#1{%
  \blx@langstrings
  \blx@bibheading\blx@theheading\blx@thetitle
  \blx@bibnote\blx@theprenote
  \begingroup
  \blx@bibinit
  \let\@noitemerr\@empty
  \let\blx@noitem\blx@warn@bibempty
  \ifnum\bibinitsep=\z@
    \let\blx@initsep\relax
  \fi
  \ifnum\bibnamesep=\z@
    \let\blx@namesep\relax
  \fi
  \csuse{blx@hook@bibinit}%
  \csuse{blx@hook@bibinit@next}%
  % copy filtered list of entries to internal list macro
  \def\blx@do##1{%
    \blx@ifdata{##1}{%
      \begingroup
      \blx@getdata{##1}%
      \blx@bibcheck
      \iftoggle{blx@skipentry}{}{%
        \global\let\blx@noitem\@empty
        \listadd\blx@tempa{##1}}%
      \endgroup}{}}%
  \let\blx@done\relax
  \blx@listloop{#1}%
  % tabular output for each item in list macro
  \def\do##1{\bbx@tab@label{##1} & \bbx@tab@item{##1}\\}%
  \csuse{blx@env@\blx@theenv}%
  \dolistloop{\blx@tempa}%
  \csuse{blx@endenv@\blx@theenv}%
  \blx@bibnote\blx@thepostnote
  \endgroup
  \endgroup% this closed a goup opened by \printbibtabular
}

\def\bbx@tab@label#1{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@getdata{#1}%
  \blx@setdefaultrefcontext{#1}%
  \blx@setoptions@type\abx@field@entrytype
  \blx@setoptions@entry
  \blx@thelabelnumber
  \blx@initsep
  \blx@namesep
  \csuse{blx@hook@bibitem}%
  \addtocounter{instcount}\@ne
  \blx@anchor
  \csuse{bbx@tabenv@\blx@theenv}\relax
  \endgroup
}

\def\bbx@tab@item#1{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@getdata{#1}%
  \blx@setoptions@type\abx@field@entrytype
  \blx@setoptions@entry
  \blx@thelabelnumber
  \csuse{blx@hook@bibitem}%
  \csuse{blx@item@\blx@theenv}\relax
  \blx@execute
  \blx@initunit
  \blx@beglangbib
  \bibsentence
  \blx@pagetracker
  \blx@driver\abx@field@entrytype
  \blx@postpunct
  \blx@endlangbib
  \endgroup
}

% user-level command for defining tabular bibliography format
\newrobustcmd*{\defbibtabular}[5]{%
  \long\csdef{blx@env@#1}{#2}%
  \long\csdef{blx@endenv@#1}{#3}%
  \long\csdef{bbx@tabenv@#1}{#4}%
  \long\csdef{blx@item@#1}{#5}}

\makeatother

% sortname labels (a robust style should add provision for missing labelnames)
\newbibmacro*{sortname}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\printtext[bold]{No name given.}%
     \PackageWarning{biblatex}{No labelname for entry \thefield{entrykey},\MessageBreak
       we need to think of something else}}
    {\printnames[sortname]{labelname}%
     \iffieldequalstr{labelnamesource}{editor}
       {\setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}}
       {\iffieldequalstr{labelnamesource}{translator}
          {\setunit{\printdelim{translatortypedelim}}%
           \usebibmacro{translator+othersstrg}}
          {}}}}

% bibitem hook to suppress redundant sortname list
\newbibmacro*{omitsortname}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {}
    {\clearname{\thefield{labelnamesource}}}}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\usepackage{longtable}
% demo new tabular bibliography format
% I strongly prefer left-aligned with fixed width (L)
% over justified (p) here
% longtable for tables that break over pages
\defbibtabular{bibtabular}
  {\def\arraystretch{2}%
   \begin{longtable}{@{}L{\dimexpr0.3\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax}L{\dimexpr0.7\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax}@{}}}
  {\end{longtable}}
  {\usebibmacro{sortname}}
  {\usebibmacro{omitsortname}}

\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \printfield{shorttitle}%
  \printunit*{\addspace}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{chickenlittle,
    author      = {Jesus Bisbal and Deirdre Lawless and Bing Wu and Jane Grimson and Vincent Wade and Ray Richardson and Donie O'Sullivan},
    title       = {A Survey of Research into Legacy System Migration},
    shorttitle  = {Legacy Migration},
    institution = {Trinity College},
    publisher   = {Trinity College},
    year        = {1997},
    url         = {http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.50.9051},
    urldate     = {2018-07-11}
}

@online{incmigration,
    author      = {Michael L. Brodie and Michael Stonebraker},
    title       = {DARWIN: On the Incremental Migration of Legacy Information Systems 1},
    shorttitle  = {Incremental Migration},
    year        = {1993},
    institution = {University of California},
    publisher   = {University of California},
    month       = {3},
    urldate     = {2018-07-11},
    url         = {http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.70.2950}
}

@online{porting,
    author      = {{Microsoft Corporation}},
    title       = {Porting to .NET Core from .NET Framework},
    shorttitle  = {Porting in .NET},
    date        = {2016-06-20},
    url         = {https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/},
    urldate     = {2018-06-26}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{porting,incmigration,chickenlittle,
  sigfridsson,ctan,westfahl:frontier,
  knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,worman,geer,nussbaum}

\printbibtabular
\end{document}
```

[image]

Tabular bibliographies more complicated because the usual setup assumes that bibliographies are ultimately created using some kind of list environment. Since lists are populated in a manner very similar to normal paragraphs of text there is nothing special going on there. With tables, on the other hand a few extra things have to be done.

This solution allows for complete customisation of a two-column tabular bibliography, where the first column is defined via `\defbibtabular` and the second column is populated by the bibliography driver as usual.

Comment: Thank you very much @moewe !
I only got one issue left with this solution: There is no space between the shorttitle and the title. I'm not able to figure out where to add a \space here. I'm only 2 weeks into the latex journey...

Comment: @Skyfreak Fixed.

Comment: Some heroes don't wear capes. Thank you :)

Comment: @Skyfreak I assume that is because there is a strict [*No capes* policy now](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M68ndaZSKa8). If the answer helped you, you may want to consider accepting it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I just realised, that sorting doesn't work any longer with your custom style. I used to sort my bib by author, date (ascending), title. 

I'll update the MWE with better entries for testing in a second.

Comment: @Skyfreak Add `sorting=nyt`, but please note that it makes little sense to sort name>year>title when the style is essentially author-title, the more natural sorting would be name>title(>year). If that does not help, please ask a *new* question.

Comment: It didn't work. I asked a new [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/441629/biblatex-doesnt-sort-my-bib-using-a-custom-style)