# Indentation of second line of the bibliography entries with author-year block

Tags: biblatex

I read the following post on how to add an author-year block to each bibliography entry: [Adding an [AuthorYear] block at the beginning of bibliography entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11827/adding-an-authoryear-block-at-the-beginning-of-bibliography-entries). My code looks just like it does in the solution.

At the moment my bibliography looks like this:
[image: momentan]

It comes very close to what my bibliography should look like. However I would like to change the indentation of the second line of each bibliography entry, so that it is in line with the fist line of the bibliography entry.

Alternatively it would also work to create a fixed block for the bibliography entries similar to this: [Creating a bibliography with fixed indention and authoryear labels using biblatex and biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348126/creating-a-bibliography-with-fixed-indention-and-authoryear-labels-using-biblate). That solution doesn't work for me, because it uses the horizontal space between label and bibliography entry.

If I use this solution, it looks like this:
[image: loesungtest]

From what I understand, it isn't possible to customize a label so that it looks like the author year block. That's why it was added additionally. As we can see, the second entry seems to have a label additionally to the author year block.

I would like to have a similar look with an author year block instead of a label.

The **solution by moewe** looks like this: (note: I only used moewe's new code without the code from [Adding an [AuthorYear] block at the beginning of bibliography entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11827/adding-an-authoryear-block-at-the-beginning-of-bibliography-entries))

[image]

**SOLUTION:** For everyone interested, the missing label was due to two lines of additional code needed if you use the authoryear-icomp style.

This is my code with moewes solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
citestyle=authoryear-icomp,
bibstyle=authortitle,
sorting=nyt,
firstinits=true,
sortlocale=de_DE,
hyperref=true,
url=true,
doi=false,
eprint=false,
maxcitenames=1,
useprefix=true
]{biblatex}


\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

\addbibresource{Literatur.bib}

\makeatletter
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.5\baselineskip plus 0.5\baselineskip}

\newsavebox\ay@labelbox
\newlength{\labwidthsameline}
\setlength{\labwidthsameline}{6em}

\newbibmacro{labelwidthbib}{%
  \begingroup
  \DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperref}{##1}%
  \csuse{blx@hook@cite}%
  \csuse{blx@hook@citekey}%
  \global\undef\cbx@lasthash
  \global\undef\cbx@lastyear
  \citetrackerfalse\pagetrackerfalse\backtrackerfalse
  \defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxcitenames}%
  \printtext[brackets]{\usebibmacro{cite}}%
  \endgroup
} 
%-----------------------
\newbibmacro{kicklabel}{% 
  \sbox\ay@labelbox{\usebibmacro{labelwidthbib}}%
  \global\togglefalse{blx@insert}%
  \ifdim\wd\ay@labelbox>\labwidthsameline
    \leavevmode\newline
  \fi
}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}%
  {\list
    {\usebibmacro{labelwidthbib}}%
    {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labwidthsameline}%
     \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
     \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
     \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
     \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
     \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
     \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}}%
      {\endlist}%
      {\item\usebibmacro{kicklabel}}
\makeatother


\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},}%et al  statt u.a.


\begin{document}

%Testcitation
\textcite{Gluck.1991}
\parencite{Best.2016a}

\newpage

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This is the .bib file:

```
@misc{Best.2016a,
 author = {Best, Isabelle and Orozaliev, Janybek},
 title = {{Renewable Low-Temperature District Heating for a New Housing   Area in Kassel, Germany -- A Case Study of IEA EBC Annex 64}},
 abstract = {},
 date = {2016-05-25},
 pagerange = {14},
}


@book{Gluck.1991,
 author = {Gl{\"u}ck, Bernd},
 year = {1991},
 title = {{Zustands- und Stoffwerte}},
 edition = {2., bearb. u. erw. Aufl.},
 publisher = {{Verlag f{\"u}r Bauwesen GmbH}},
 isbn = {3-345-00487-9},
 subtitle = {{Wasser, Dampf, Luft ; Verbrennungsrechnung}},
 location = {Berlin},
 series = {{Bausteine der Heizungstechnik}},
 abstract = {},
 pagetotal = {140},
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand why the second solution does not work for you. Specifically, what is the difference between the 'label' and  'author year block'. Maybe you can explain what would have to be different. Ideally with a picture mock-up what you have now and what needs to be changed.

Comment: I think you want `\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}`. If you want space between the entries increase `\bibitemsep`.

Comment: What if you use only the code from the second link and not the first link?

Comment: @David Purton The \setlength{\bibhang}{0pt} doesn't do what I want, because it only changes the second line.

Comment: @Weena, no worries. I misunderstood question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a slightly modified version of my answer to [Creating a bibliography with fixed indention and authoryear labels using biblatex and biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/348126/35864)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber,dashed=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.5\baselineskip plus 0.5\baselineskip}

\newsavebox\ay@labelbox
\newlength{\labwidthsameline}
\setlength{\labwidthsameline}{6em}

\newbibmacro{labelwidthbib}{%
  \begingroup
  \delimcontext{parencite}%
  \DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperref}{##1}%
  \csuse{blx@hook@cite}%
  \csuse{blx@hook@citekey}%
  \global\undef\cbx@lasthash
  \global\undef\cbx@lastyear
  \citetrackerfalse\pagetrackerfalse\backtrackerfalse
  \defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxcitenames}%
  \printtext[brackets]{\usebibmacro{cite}}%
  \endgroup
} 
%-----------------------
\newbibmacro{kicklabel}{% 
  \sbox\ay@labelbox{\usebibmacro{labelwidthbib}}%
  \global\togglefalse{blx@insert}%
  \ifdim\wd\ay@labelbox>\labwidthsameline
    \leavevmode\newline
  \fi
}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}%
  {\list
    {\usebibmacro{labelwidthbib}}%
    {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labwidthsameline}%
     \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
     \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
     \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
     \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
     \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
     \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}}%
  {\endlist}%
  {\item\usebibmacro{kicklabel}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,knuth:ct:a}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I want. However one of my entries seems to have no label, any idea why?

Comment: @Weena Please show an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) of the problematic entry.

Comment: I posted a MWE in my question.

Comment: @Weena If the solution is helpful then you should up-vote it (not up-voting does not incentivize the poster to answer follow-up questions in the comments). If the solution answers your question and you think it the best answer you should also give a a green tick.

Comment: @moewe I already tried to do that but it seems I don't have enough reputation, so that it is shown. Sorry, your answer is really helpful!

Comment: @Weena Since you use `authoryear-icomp`, you need two more lines in the code. Please see the edited answer.

Comment: @moewe I think your two lines of additional code did it, thank you!