# Tailoring Biblatex for De Gruyters "Holzforschung"

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, overleaf, xkeyval

*(190816, 2249 CET, updated according to the comments of "**Mensch**")*

*190818, 1332 CET, update regarding error message on `articlein`*

Hi, all,

I'm trying to make my bibliography look like:

[image: at]

but for the moment I'm stuck in something that looks like:

[image: Present situation of references]

so, in particular, I wonder how I

1. get rid of the "." after "volume"
2. get rid of the ", " before pages

Besides that, I think that I have made it look as "it should".

I attach my code below:

```
\documentclass[english,final,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%(only for the pdftex engine)
\usepackage[big]{dgruyter}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
\usepackage[format=hang,singlelinecheck=0,font={sf,small},labelfont=bf]{subfig}
%% format=hang, bra veta om
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,%ext-authoryear,%authoryear,%nature,%bwl-    FU,%authoryear,
        citestyle=authoryear,
        natbib=true,
        hyperref=true,
        url=false,        
        doi=false,         
        isbn=false, 
        sorting=nyt,
        %bibstyle=authoryear,
        giveninits=true,
        maxcitenames=2,
        uniquelist=false, % denna som gör att man får a) och b) i stället för fler efternamn
        maxbibnames=99,
        uniquename=false,
        dashed=false,
        articlein=false,
        url=false, 
        doi=false, 
        isbn=false, 
        dashed=false,
        backend=biber]{biblatex}
%\setlength\bibhang{2pt} % default value: \parindent
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}
%\DeclareFieldFormat*{year}{#1} 
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1} 
%
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
    \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
%
% removes pagination (p./pp.) before page numbers
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{:#1}
%
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
%
\DeclareFieldFormat*{volume}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{number}{(#1)}

\addbibresource{mojiref.bib}

\begin{document}

\articletype{}



\maketitle

There is one method, attributed to \citep{wilhelmy1863ueber} that is very simple to use and provides accurate, consistent, and reproducible data especially for rough, heterogeneous, and hygroscopic materials such as wood \citep{lander1993systematic}. 


\printbibliography%[env=bibnumeric]
% ovanstående gör att man får radindraget borttaget. Inte bra här och nu,


\end{document}
```

And here are the two references:

```
@article{lander1993systematic,
  title={A systematic comparison of contact angle methods},
  author={Lander, Lorraine M and Siewierski, Lisa M and Brittain, William J and Vogler, Erwin A},
  journal={Langmuir},
  volume={9},
  number={8},
  pages={2237--2239},
  year={1993},
  publisher={ACS Publications}
}

@article{wilhelmy1863ueber,
  title={Ueber die Abh{\"a}ngigkeit der Capillarit{\"a}ts-Constanten des Alkohols von Substanz und Gestalt des benetzten festen K{\"o}rpers},
  author={Wilhelmy, Ludwig},
  journal={Ann. Phys.},%{Annalen der Physik},
  volume={195},
  number={6},
  pages={177--217},
  year={1863},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
```

I hope it makes sense, and that someone is able to help me out with this one.

*Added 190818:*

The `articlein=false` added from the advice of **moewe** results this error message in Overleaf.

[image]

/Lars

Comment: Well, please make your code snippet compilable and add the bib entry for the cited document to your question. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Sorry. I'll put up more information soon.

Comment: Now I have updated the original post. I hope that all necessary information is there this time. Otherwise, just tell me!

Comment: Re your most recent update: As I mentioned in the last comment under my answer, the system on Overleaf is too old to support `biblatex-ext` and in particular its `articlein` option. You will get errors if you try to use it. My comment contains a link to alternative code that should work with the outdated Overleaf system (https://gist.github.com/moewew/e9ae043f49e057abfb344d96cb134f82).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are preparing a manuscript for submission with a journal, double check that they can accept `biblatex` submissions. Compared to BibTeX `biblatex` requires quite a different workflow on the publisher's side and their tools might not be equipped to deal with `biblatex` as required. Furthermore, publishers aren't generally known to run the most up-to-date LaTeX systems, which means that there is a very real risk of version incompatibilities. See [Biblatex: submitting to a journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864).

Anyway, if you want to go on with `biblatex` despite these warnings (for example because the publisher only wants the PDF) or you only want to emulate the style of the journal, this should get you started.

The MWE uses `biblatex-ext`'s `ext-authoryear` as basis, because it has some simpler tools available to deal with the punctuation between the `volume` and `number` fields. The code has also been updated to use less intrusive methods elsewhere. In general field formats should contain no leading or trailing punctuation (as in `\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{:#1}`)

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-authoryear,
  giveninits=true, uniquename=false,
  maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=99,
  articlein=false,
  url=false, doi=false, isbn=false, dashed=false,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{issuetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat{maintitle}{#1}

\renewcommand*{\volnumdelim}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {\addcolon}
    {\addcomma}%
  \space}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{#1}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{lande,
  author  = {Stig Lande and Mats Westin and Marc Schneider},
  title   = {Properties of Furfurylated Wood},
  journal = {Scandinavian Journal of Forest Research},
  volume  = {19},
  number  = {suppl~5},
  pages   = {22-30},
  year    = {2004},
  doi     = {10.1080/0282758041001915},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,lande}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lande, S., Westin, M., Schneider, M. (2004). Properties of Furfurylated Wood. Scandinavian Journal of Forest Research 19(suppl 5): 22–30.]

Comment: Where/how do I get `biblatex-ext` installed when using `overleaf`?

Comment: I saw some discussion on [this discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497760/how-can-i-have-references-list-with-author-year-format) regarding `overleaf` and `biblatex-ext`.

Comment: The publisher says: _start_ _quote_ Alternatively, the `biblatex` package can be used. Be aware, however, that there is an abundance of options which have not all been tested for compatibility with the `dgruyter` package. The following seem to work fine for the numeric style: • `\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}` to load the package, • `\addbibresource{BIBFILE}` to load the .bib-file, • `\printbibliography[env=bibnumeric]` to output the bibliography. With author-year citation you have to skip the optional argument of `\printbibliography` _end_ _quote_.

Comment: Taken from [this document](https://www.degruyter.com/staticfiles/pdfs/AUTH_DG_LaTeX-Template.zip)

Comment: @LarsAbrahamsson Ugh, Overleaf are using an outdated LaTeX system that doesn't have `biblatex-ext` installed. It becomes increasingly frustrating to support the old version on Overleaf, so if possible I would recommend you install an up-to-date TeX system (MikTeX or TeX live 2019) locally. You can also nudge Overleaf support and ask them to provide an option to use a more up-to-date TeX system on their end. If you can't do either of those, try https://gist.github.com/moewew/e9ae043f49e057abfb344d96cb134f82

Comment: Cool. Thanks a lot. I'll contact the staff at Overleaf, but for the moment, I used the example that you sent. Since I have problems installing MikTex on my work laptop. Only one bad thing with the code you provided, the "." after "({year})" came back. But I will try to solve it myself if I'm able.

Comment: It seems like that `\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace}` makes the "." after "({year})" disappear.

Comment: @LarsAbrahamsson It would be nicer to use `\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addspace}`. I updated both the answer and the code at https://gist.github.com/moewew/e9ae043f49e057abfb344d96cb134f82 accordingly.