# How do I get a cite format [Lastname year] and corresponding reference list

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I have been trying to find out how to make citations to look like

[Lastname year]

in the text. As an example:

> The results are from [Smith 2016].

And in the references the list would have a line.

> [Smith 2016]    Smith, A.J, Results, Journal 5 (2016).

How can I do that?

And no, "et al." cannot ne visible, **not** like this:

> The results are from [Smith et al. 2016].

At this point any command that gets rid of that "et al." is acceptable, even multiplatform post processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/420601/191948 can be tweaked to remove the "et al.":

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sorting=nty,style=alphabetic]{biblatex} 
\renewcommand{\labelalphaothers}{}
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate[]{\labelelement{\field[names=1]{author}}
                             \labelelement{\literal{\addspace}}
                             \labelelement{\field{year}}
                             }

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}


\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When `biblatex` 3.13 is released with the changes for https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/861, it will also be possible to use [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/422933/35864) to the same question, which does not abuse the `alphabetic` style.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! The key seems to be the \DeclareAlphaTemplate that enables lots of other format as well.