# biblatex: comma between author and year in bibliography when using ext-authoryear style with introcite=label

Tags: biblatex, macros, bibliographies, formatting

I am using `biblatex-ext` with `introcite=label` to get a citation style like shown in the following question:

[Creating a bibliography with fixed indention and authoryear labels using biblatex and biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348126/creating-a-bibliography-with-fixed-indention-and-authoryear-labels-using-biblate)

This gives me labels with a space between author and year both in the label and the bibliography. However, I am required to have a space between author and year in the label and a comma between author and year in the bibliography entry. So I need something like that:

```
Tietze et al. 2012    Tietze, Ulrich; Schenk, Christoph, 2012.
                      Halbleiterschaltungstechnik. ...
```

Note that I used the following solution to remove the parentheses around the year: [biblatex: How to remove the parentheses around the year in authoryear style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12254/biblatex-how-to-remove-the-parentheses-around-the-year-in-authoryear-style/40710#40710)

While searching for a solution, I found

```
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
```

but this only works for the label making the above entry

```
Tietze et al., 2012    Tietze, Ulrich; Schenk, Christoph 2012.
                      Halbleiterschaltungstechnik. ...
```

This is the opposite of what I need. I need a space between author and year in the label and a comma in the bibliography entry.

Comment: `\renewcommand*{\nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}`?

Comment: `\nametitledelim` is context sensitive, so `\DeclareDelimFormat{nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}` is probably better. (Same for `\nameyeardelim` actually.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [David Purton](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/87678/david-purton) in [the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504197/biblatex-comma-between-author-and-year-in-bibliography-when-using-ext-authoryea#comment1273634_504197), `nameyeardelim` is a context-sensitive delimiter. This means that you can give it different definitions for the bibliography and citations. The `introcite` label has the context `bbx@introcite`, which is different from the context `bib` for the rest of the bibliography, so we can use different values for `nameyeardelim` here.

The default `nameyeardelim` for all contexts is `\addspace`, so we only need to change the delimiter for the `bib` context to a comma followed by a space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear, backend=biber, introcite=label, dashed=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.5\baselineskip plus 0.5\baselineskip}
\setlength{\introcitewidth}{6em}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat{biblabeldate}{#1}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,knuth:ct:a}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998//Sigfridsson, Emma and Ulf Ryde, 1998.]