# autoryear-ext with introcite=label: Remove extradate letter from bibliography entry but not from label

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, formatting

I am asked to produce a bibliography in authoryear style with only the first author in label. In case of an ambitious label, a letter is appended to the year. This can easily be produced with the following code (taken from [Creating a bibliography with fixed indention and authoryear labels using biblatex and biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348126/creating-a-bibliography-with-fixed-indention-and-authoryear-labels-using-biblate)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear, backend=biber, maxcitenames=1, uniquename=false, uniquelist=false, introcite=label, dashed=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Shepard2001a,
  author = {Shepard, Frank and Fisher, John},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Livestock management},
}
@book{Shepard2001b,
  author = {Shepard, Frank and Farmer, Boris},
  year = {2001},
  title = {On food supplies},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} % if you’re using biblatex\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.5\baselineskip plus 0.5\baselineskip}
\setlength{\introcitewidth}{6em}

\begin{document}
  \cite{Shepard2001a, Shepard2001b}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

As you can see, I am using `ext-authoryear` from `biblatex-ext` with `introcite=label`.

The result looks like that:
[image]

This is good, except that in the bibliography entry the letter appended to the year should be removed. I have marked the 'offending' letter with a red line. That is: I need the letter in the label but not in the bibliography entry itself. An entry for the MWE should look like that:

```
Shepard et al. 2001a
   Shepard, Frank and Boris Farmer (2001), ...
```

I could not figure out, where to change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replacing `\printdateextra` by `\printdate` in the `data+extradate` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear, backend=biber, maxcitenames=1, uniquename=false, uniquelist=false, introcite=label, dashed=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Shepard2001a,
  author = {Shepard, Frank and Fisher, John},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Livestock management},
}
@book{Shepard2001b,
  author = {Shepard, Frank and Farmer, Boris},
  year = {2001},
  title = {On food supplies},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} % if you’re using biblatex\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.5\baselineskip plus 0.5\baselineskip}
\setlength{\introcitewidth}{6em}

\makeatletter
  \renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
    \iffieldundef{labelyear}
      {}
      {\printtext[\blx@delimcontext labeldate]{%
         \iflabeldateisdate
           {\printfield{issue}%
            \setunit*{\addspace}%
            \printdate}
           {\printlabeldateextra}}}}%
  \renewbibmacro*{bbx:ifmergeddate}{\iflabeldateisdate}%
  \renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
    \usebibmacro{bbx:ifmergeddate}
      {}
      {\printtext[issuedate]{%
         \printfield{issue}%
         \setunit*{\addspace}%
         \printdate}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \cite{Shepard2001a, Shepard2001b}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1) But note that this is the code from `mergedate=maximum` while the default (which the OP is using because they haven't defined anything else) would be the code from `mergedate=compact`. In case you choose the code for the appropriate `mergedate` one only needs to change the `date+extradate` bibmacro and not the other two. Last but not least we probably want to replace the remaining `\printlabeldateextra` with `\printlabeldate` as well.

Answer (score 1):

The code for date printing varies with the chosen `mergedate` setting. The preset is `mergedate=true` which is equivalent to `mergedate=compact`, where the modifications can be kept at bay as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear, backend=biber,
  maxcitenames=1, uniquename=false, uniquelist=false,
  introcite=label, dashed=false]{biblatex}

\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.5\baselineskip plus 0.5\baselineskip}
\setlength{\introcitewidth}{6em}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[\blx@delimcontext labeldate]{%
       \iflabeldateisdate
         {\printdate}
         {\printlabeldate}}}}
\makeatother


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Shepard2001a,
  author = {Shepard, Frank and Fisher, John},
  year   = {2001},
  title  = {Livestock management},
}
@book{Shepard2001b,
  author = {Shepard, Frank and Farmer, Boris},
  year   = {2001},
  title  = {On food supplies},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \cite{Shepard2001a, Shepard2001b}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Shepard et al. 2001a/Shepard, Frank and Boris Farmer (2001). On food supplies.//Shepard et al. 2001b/Shepard, Frank and John Fisher (2001). Livestock management.]

[The other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/504438/35864) used the code for `mergedate=maximum` as a basis and redefined `bbx:ifmergeddate` and `issue+date` as well, even though that was not necessary. In the code here we also removed the `extradate` info in the case where `\iflabeldateisdate` is false.

---

Another option with different output would be to combine `authoryear` citations with an `authortitle` bibliography.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, bibstyle=ext-authortitle, citestyle=ext-authoryear,
  sorting=nyt,
  maxcitenames=1, uniquename=false, uniquelist=false,
  introcite=label, dashed=false]{biblatex}

\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.5\baselineskip plus 0.5\baselineskip}
\setlength{\introcitewidth}{6em}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Shepard2001a,
  author = {Shepard, Frank and Fisher, John},
  year   = {2001},
  title  = {Livestock management},
}
@book{Shepard2001b,
  author = {Shepard, Frank and Farmer, Boris},
  year   = {2001},
  title  = {On food supplies},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \cite{Shepard2001a, Shepard2001b}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Shepard et al. 2001a/Shepard, Frank and Boris Farmer. On food supplies. 2001.//Shepard et al. 2001b/Shepard, Frank and John Fisher. Livestock management. 2001.]